# Generate API key for API Endpoints from Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've got an API in cloud run that I want to secure using API keys.  I've been using https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run#configure_esp to configure the endpoints for the API.  I've successfully created the API and the developer portal.  My goal is for users to log in to a mobile and/or web app (using Firebase) and then be able to generate an API key that allows them to access the API.  I've only found documentation on manually creating API keys for users: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys#create-an-api-key-for-each-caller.

My authentication scheme is a common pattern (github, for example, uses this pattern) and I'm surprised its so difficult on GCP. I was able to successfully implement this scheme in AWS.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed nothing, it's simply not possible. API key security is not recommended by Google (weaker than OAuth2 authentication mechanism) and all the operations around the API key are only available for Google internal call.

Did you try to validate by yourself an API key? Same result: not possible. Only Cloud Endpoint can do this by calling internal Google API, nothing public.

If you use Firebase, I recommend you to use Firebase Auth to authenticate the users on your API. It's [integrated to CLoud Endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase) and you simply have to update your security definition.